# SQL Server - Sum of difference between each consecutive entry in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have at table in the format :

```
SomeID  SomeData

1       3
2       7
3       9
4       10
5       14
.       .
.       .
```

I want to find sum of difference between consecutive elements in this table.
i.e ( (7-3) + (9-7) + (10-9) + (14-10) + ....)

Which is the best way to do this

Comment: can you specify which version of SQL server you are using, if >=2012 you can use lead, lag functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method which should work on any version of SQL Server is a self-join:

```
SELECT
    t1.SomeID,
    t2.SomeData - t1.SomeData AS diff
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.SomeID = t2.SomeID - 1;
```

This assumes you want to report the diff as lead value of `SomeData` for a given row minus the current value of `SomeData`.  This query also assumes that `SomeID` is a continuous sequence.

Using `LEAD`:

```
SELECT
    SomeID,
    LEAD(SomeData, 1) OVER (ORDER BY SomeID) - SomeData AS diff
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: The table is pretty huge, which is the least expensive ? LEAD or self join ?

Comment: You may try using `LEAD` as well, which would probably be faster than a self-join.  But, this assumes your version of SQL Server supports `LEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQl Server 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
        Someid INT ,
        SomeData INT
    );

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES ( 1, 3 ) ,
       ( 2, 7 ) ,
       ( 3, 9 ) ,
       ( 4, 10 ) ,
       ( 5, 14 );


SELECT *
FROM   #temp;

SELECT SUM(LeadSomeData) AS FinalSum
FROM   (   SELECT LEAD(SomeData) OVER ( ORDER BY Someid ASC ) - SomeData AS LeadSomeData
           FROM   #temp ) t;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
Select Sum(d2.data-d1.data) from #data d1 join #data d2 on d1.id+1 = d2.id
```

Schema:

```
Create table #data (id int, data int)
Insert into #data values 
(1, 3),
(2, 7),
(3, 9),
(4, 10),
(5, 14)
```